# SAS URLs not working

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to create a SAS URL for a blob storage container.  I've tried multiple storage accounts and multiple methods of creating the SAS, and all of them give this result when I test the SAS URL in a browser:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:d95bf34f-0001-0022-4430-b1a25b000000 Time:2016-05-18T18:12:30.5552096Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was rl 2016-05-18T18:10:00Z 2016-05-19T18:10:00Z /blob/cloudappmanager/$root 2015-04-05
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

I tried [Storage Explorer](https://storageexplorer.com) (right-click container, Get SAS, click OK with defaults):
[image]

I tried the old Storage Explorer:

[image]

And I tried PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\virklba> $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName msuscoreaprod 
cmdlet New-AzureStorageContext at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
StorageAccountKey: xxxxxxxxx

PS C:\Users\virklba> New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name aadlogs -Context $context -FullUri -Permission rl
https://msuscoreaprod.blob.core.windows.net/aadlogs?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxx&se=2016-05-18T19%3A47%3A56Z&sp=rl
```

All with the same result.  Is anyone else seeing this behavior, or is it just me?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your local machine's system clock is up-to-date? Also: Would you mind trying an experiment, setting the start time to, say, an hour (or a day) in the past?

Comment: System clock is accurate.  I tried again setting the start time to yesterday, same result.  I've also talked to one of our consultants; he's seeing the same behavior on a separate machine, separate Azure environment.

Comment: What is the URL that you are testing in the browser?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are creating a SAS on the container, and it looks like you are trying to read the container in the browser. When I paste the container SAS into the browser, I get the same error you are getting.

The container SAS (with read permissions) gives you read access to the blobs in the container. So you need to append a blob name to the SAS before you paste it into the browser, in order to read a blob.

For example, this will not work:

https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/lotsofblobs?st=2016-05-18T22%3A49%3A00Z&se=2016-05-19T22%3A59%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=62WHwaZGI60ub1hYcQyKg1%2FE%2F1w9HUrOPGorzoWDLvE%3D

This does work, with myblob.txt appended to the base URL:

https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/lotsofblobs/myblob.txt?st=2016-05-18T22%3A49%3A00Z&se=2016-05-19T22%3A59%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=62WHwaZGI60ub1hYcQyKg1%2FE%2F1w9HUrOPGorzoWDLvE%3D

Please also see Gaurav Mantri's detailed explanation here: [Azure Shared Access Signature - Signature did not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, try connecting the storage account first, then the blob.