# Azure SDK PHP SAS for container

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using these methods to get sas container access. How can I update them to access to a container properly? I get the following error: "Signature did not match". I can get access to a single blob but I can't find the fix to allow access to a container.

URL:[https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/container?se=2017-03-01T11%3A30%3A25.0000000Z&st=2017-03-01T10%3A07%3A05.0000000Z&sr=c&sp=rwdl&sig=*SIGNATURE*&sv=2015-04-05&spr=https](https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/container?se=2017-03-01T11%3A30%3A25.0000000Z&st=2017-03-01T10%3A07%3A05.0000000Z&sr=c&sp=rwdl&sig=_SIGNATURE_&sv=2015-04-05&spr=https)

Error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:7dd5dba8-0001-0035-5278-926fe6000000 Time:2017-03-01T10:40:41.6498650Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was rwdl 2017-03-01T10:07:05.0000000Z 2017-03-01T11:30:25.0000000Z /blob/storage/$root https 2015-04-05
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Code:

```
public function generateContainerSAS() {
       if(!$this->existsContainer()){
             $this->blobClient->createContainer($this->container);
       }    
       $start =  $this->isoDate(time() - 2000);
       $expiry = $this->isoDate(time() + 3000);
       $signature = $this->getSASForContainer(AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,$this->container,
               'rwdl',$start, $expiry,AZURE_STORAGE_PRIMARY_KEY);

       $sharedAccessUrl = $this->getContainerUrl(AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,$this->container,
               'c','rwdl',$start, $expiry,$signature);

       return $sharedAccessUrl;
    }


function getContainerUrl($accountName,$container,$resourceType,$permissions,$start, $expiry,$_signature){
        /* Create the signed query part */
        $_parts = array();
        $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry))?'se=' . urlencode($expiry):'';
        $_parts[] = (!empty($start))?'st=' . urlencode($start):'';
        $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
        $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions))?'sp=' . $permissions:'';
        $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
        $_parts[] = 'sv=2015-04-05';
        $_parts[] = 'spr=https';

        /* Create the signed blob URL */
        $_url = 'https://'
        . $accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'
        . $container . '?'
        . implode('&', $_parts);

        return $_url;
    }


  function getSASForContainer($accountName,$container, $permissions, $start, $expiry,$key){

        $_arraysign = array();
        $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
        $_arraysign[] = $start;
        $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
        $_arraysign[] = "/blob/" . $accountName . '/' . $container;
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_arraysign[] = 'https';
        $_arraysign[] = "2015-04-05"; //the API version is now required
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_arraysign[] = '';
        $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

        return base64_encode(
        hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($key), true)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Can you update your question and include the detailed error message you're getting? 2) Can you share how are you using the container SAS URL?

Comment: Of course, I updated the post :)

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind sharing the name of your container as well? I think I know why this is happening. Just needed to confirm one thing :).

Comment: Container name is 00019

Comment: I found this: $_parts[] = 'comp=list';$_parts[] = 'restype=container'; is necessary?

Comment: `I found this: $_parts[] = 'comp=list';$_parts[] = 'restype=container'; is necessary?` You read my mind, my friend :). I was about to write this thing.

Comment: Please see this answer of mine for details about this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match.