# Azure SAS and Permission

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

**GetSaSForBlobContainer**(container,SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List|SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read);

```
public static string **GetSaSForBlobContainer**(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer, SharedAccessBlobPermissions permission)
    {
        var sas = blobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = permission,
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5),//SAS Start time is back by 5 minutes to take clock skewness into consideration
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
        });
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", blobContainer.Uri, sas);
    }
```

-- When I try this, my container access in my stroge account is private.Can I list blobs in the container with Internet Explorer ? I try with blob and container access types the fail is always :

> `AuthenticationFailed`
>   
>   Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:2c504f81-0001-00ea-3815-be7271000000 Time:2017-04-25T22:47:20.9382490Z
>   
>   
>   Signature did not match. String to sign used was rl 2017-04-25T22:38:15Z 2017-04-25T22:58:15Z /blob/onlineeducation/$root 2015-12-11

But when I try this I can see the blobs  ,

```
 foreach (IListBlobItem blob in blobs)
{
   CloudBlockBlob blob1 = new CloudBlockBlob(blob.Uri);
   string name = blob1.Name;

}
```

1-)  I dont understand one thing when I create GetSaSForBlobContainer and my container access type is private what will happen (for Internet Explorer and code) ?.

2-) When I get reference without permission my private container, and then create blob uri + SAS.Example what will happen can I see my containers ? or can I only write referenced blob (my blob permission is only write)..

3-What will happen, Container uri + sas - Blob uri + sas (Permission is read) => Can I only upload the file or can I see the containers when try in Internet Explorer .

4-)What is the different here ,

- My container access type is **private** in my storage I get the reference of continer *without any permssion and SAS*,  and then create blob URI with r*ead permssion and SAS* .
- Container acces type is **private** in my storage I get the reference of container *with permssion and SAS*, and then create blob URI with *read permssion and SAS*

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by `Explorer`? Do you mean Microsoft's Azure Storage Explorer or Internet Explorer (browser)?

Comment: yes sir ,Internet Explorer I edited now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try this, my container access in my stroge account is
>   private.Can I list blobs in the container with Internet Explorer ? I
>   try with blob and container access types the fail is always

To fix this issue, first please add `List` as the permission in your SAS and then add `&restype=container&comp=list` to your request URL. For more explanation on this issue, please see this thread: [Azure Shared Access Signature - Signature did not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match).

> 1-) I dont understand one thing when I create GetSaSForBlobContainer
>   and my container access type is private what will happen (for Internet
>   Explorer and code) ?

Nothing will happen unless you do something with it :). Depending on the permissions included in SAS, user who's in possession of this SAS URL will be able to perform certain operations. For example, if you create a SAS with `List` permission then the user will be able to only list the blobs in that container. They will not be able to even download the blobs (for that the SAS must include `Read` permission).

> 2-) When I get reference without permission my private container, and
>   then create blob uri + SAS.Example what will happen can I see my
>   containers ? or can I only write referenced blob (my blob permission
>   is only write)..

No, you can't see your containers as the SAS is for a container only. Again because you're including `Read` permission, you will only be able to read blob contents. You will not be able to upload the blobs.

> 3-What will happen, Container uri + sas - Blob uri + sas (Permission
>   is read) => Can I only upload the file or can I see the containers
>   when try in Internet Explorer .

No, with `Read` permission you can't upload the file. You can't even view the blobs list with `Read` permission. For this you would need `List` permission.

Regarding #4, there's no difference till the time you actually use that SAS URL. In 1st case you will get an error and in the 2nd one you will be able to see the blob.

Comment: All you answers are precious for me .I appreciate you    Regarding4# --  My container access type is private in my storage 
I get the reference of continer without any permssion and SAS, 
and then create blob URI with read permssion and SAS .  => I understand here I can go only to my blob and download it
 because of read permission, but when I try to see the container of blob (downloadable blob) , I cant see the container. ( I thought it doesnt matter what I create for blob permission and SAS ,container without permission 
 and without SAS I can see  it. )