# Azure Blob Container, Can't Generate Token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on azure storage but I cannot create a proper SAS token to pass to my frontend javascript. Following multiple tutorials and examples, I can't seem to get a working token for JS.

I'm validating my token at on the tutorial here so that my own javascript doesn't get in my way: https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html

I've spent hours trying out different solutions, but my token generated looks so similar to the one generated by azure.  What am I missing?

### code

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

//Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
//In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write;

//Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
string sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

//Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
return sasContainerToken;
```

Comment: Your code for generating SAS token looks ok. Can you share your JS code? What’s the error you’re getting?

Comment: What happens when you try to use the token? Have you tried setting the start-time slightly in the past (e.g. current time - 5 minutes)? This will at least rule out clock-drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a token for the storage account instead. The permissions in the tutorial listed are granted by the storage account policy.

```
public static string GenerateAccountSASToken(string connectionString)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

    SharedAccessAccountPolicy accountpolicy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy();
    accountpolicy.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-24);
    accountpolicy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
    accountpolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Add | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.ProcessMessages | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Update | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write;
    accountpolicy.Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob;
    accountpolicy.ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service;
    return  storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(accountpolicy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue, have you tried to use JS to create a SAS token.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs');
var SasConstants = azure.Constants.AccountSasConstants;

var blobService = azure.createBlobService();

var containerName = 'containername';
var blobName = 'blobname';

var startDate = new Date('');
var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
expiryDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

var sharedAccessPolicy = {
  AccessPolicy: {
    Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.ADD + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.CREATE+ azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
    Start: startDate,
    Expiry: expiryDate
  },
};

var token = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(containerName, null, sharedAccessPolicy);
```

Comment: I have not. I will give it a shot when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, the code is ok for generating SAS token.  If you want to list the blobs in the container, you need to add `&comp=list&restype=container` to your SAS URL. Then it should work.

```
Get https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test?sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxx&sp=rwl&comp=list&restype=container
```

> Azure Storage Service is not able to identify if the resource you're trying to access is a blob or a container and assumes it's a blob. Since it assumes the resource type is blob, it makes use of $root blob container for SAS calculation (which you can see from your error message). Since SAS was calculated for mark blob container, you get this Signature Does Not Match error. By specifying restype=container you're telling storage service to treat the resource as container. comp=list is required as per REST API specification.

For more information, please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match).