# </Message>AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. string to sign used was w

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

I am trying to upload the file from local to azure blob storage using Azure blob storage dependency in Java Spring.

Here I’m using sas token to upload the file.
The code snippet is:-

```
BlobClient blobClient=new BlobClientBuilder().endpoint(sasTokenUri).blobName(blobName).buildClient();
blobClient.uploadFromFile(“File”);
```

Here sasTokenUri = https://domain.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/?sv=2022-11-02&se=2023-10-17To4%3A29%3A52z&sr=d&sp=w&sdd=1&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxx

Could anyone please help to identify the issue and resolve it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Local to azure blob storage using Azure blob storage

The above error occurs when you pass the wrong sas token in your code.

You can get the SAS token from the portal.

**Portal:**

Storageaccounts-> shared access signature -> check the required fields -> Generate SAS-token.

[image]

Now, I tried with the below code it successfully executed and uploaded file from local to Azure blob storage,

**Code:**

```
String sasToken = "?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-10-17T13:32:35Z&st=2023-10-17T05:32:35Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxx";
String sasTokenUri="https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/" + sasToken;
String blobName = "sample.png";
String filePath = "Your local path";

BlobClientBuilder builder = new BlobClientBuilder().endpoint(sasTokenUri).blobName(blobName);
        builder.buildClient().uploadFromFile(filePath);
System.out.println("The file is uploaded successfully.");
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Storage Blob client library for Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable)

Comment: Thank you. I gave blob name wrong one so it was not matching with sas token uri.  Now I replaced it but when I am trying to upload I’m getting already blob exists. Actually I am trying for the first time . This should not come . Any particular reason for this? Or Am I uploading wrongly?

Comment: Try with different blob name like `sample1.png`