# How to authorize encryption of data using azure key vault and blob storage in data protection system

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Created a key in `key vault`, then created a container in `blob storage` and gave the managed identity the `storage blob data contributor role`. Then generated `SAS token and URL`. The SAS has `read write and create` permissions. I also allowed the IP address of the Linux VM in both `blob storage container` and `SAS`.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri(blobUriWithSasToken))
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyIdentifier), new DefaultAzureCredential());`
```

Getting the error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An error occurred
> while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner
> exception for more information. For more information> --->
> Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to
> perform this operation.

I've tried regenerating the key and SAS tokens but still doesn't work. I've also added `comp=list&restype=container` to the SAS URL. which resolved my first error. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038429/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Did you grant the Managed Identity read access to the key in Key Vault?

Comment: This is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-configure-existing-account?tabs=azure-portal#choose-a-managed-identity-to-authorize-access-to-the-key-vault

Comment: the managed identity had the role of Key Vault Administrator and now also has the role of Key Vault Crypto Service but still doesn't work, I think I will try to PersistKeysToDbContext instead.

Comment: @CircuitSquirrel7812 Are you trying this in VM?

Comment: yes, I'm using a Linux VM for deployment

Comment: To resolve the "Azure.RequestFailedException," check these:
1. Verify SAS Token permissions (Read, Write, Create).
2. Confirm correct IP address restriction for the Linux VM.
3. Ensure the managed identity has "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role.
4. Check Key Vault access for the managed identity.
5. Confirm `DefaultAzureCredential` is using the managed identity.
6. Check Network Security Group rules for outbound connections.
7. Validate the blob URI format in `.PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage()`.